# reinstall windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall

Windows 7 has been installed on my second partition "D" drive...everything is great...I even have Virtural XP up and running...Question:  XP is still installed on my "C" drive, can I reinstall it on my "C" drive? I don't care about the old settings. I just thought I could have a fresh install of XP on it's original drive. Thanks always for all of your support.

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed be able to reinstall it on your "C" drive. Just select the proper partition during your installation. However, you might run into some difficulties if XP overwrites Windows 7's bootloader with its own (possibly wouldn't be able to boot into Windows 7). I would bet there is a solution to this problem, however.

**Update:** [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/ae4380f4-5901-4ff8-be3a-b15090cbe564) (MS TechNet Forums) is a thread that seems to show a way to get the Windows 7 bootloader back and have XP in its menu.